Removing Specific Apps from macOS Dock
In the macOS Dock, certain apps, such as a background script that I wrote and don't need to attend to, remain in the left side of the Dock even though I have dragged them out of the Dock until the 'Remove' tool tip is shown (there is no 'Remove from Dock' item shown in the app's Options submenu.
I have already enabled 'Minimize windows into application icon' and disabled 'Show suggested and recent apps in Dock' in System Settings, so the app's windows are not appearing on the Dock's right side. I know they are not in the persistent apps array since I inspected that with the terminal command: 'defaults read com.apple.dock persistent-apps'.
I’d rather not always be playing whack-a-mole every time a tool starts.
Can I change my scripts so their icons never appear in the Dock? And how do I prevent third party apps, which I cannot modify and have no preferences to do this, from appearing in the dock?
Here is an image of the dock with the two items indicated.


Thanks, Joe

If they are running, then they'll be in the Dock. Your script is an AppleScript application, not a background script?

@benwiggy: Correct. It is an AppleScript app.

Can you clarify what "whack-a-mole" you need to do, every time a tool starts? I'm failing to see the problem.

No, you cannot stop these apps from showing. Any GUI application that is running will show up in the Dock. That includes AppleScripts saved as 'applications'.
You can see in your screenshot that all those apps have a little 'dot' below them, which indicates that they are running, and not just added to the Dock for convenience.
It is possible for the Dock to show 'recent' apps; but these are in a separate group at one end. You can turn this on or off in System Settings.

Thank you. Now that I now it won't be so frustrating :)

Tap and hold on the app's dock icon until a menu pops up. Third item from the bottom is "Options", and one option is "Remove from Dock".

there is no 'Remove from Dock' item shown in the app's Options submenu after tapping and holding on the app's dock icon until a menu pops up.
